How can I group on two levels in pandas and sort the values in descending order to pick the top 5 in each group level
I have a dataframe that looks like the following



Entity Name
State
Store#




Name 1
AL
1234


Name 2
TX
4545


Name 3
TX
6789


Name 2
CA
0123


Name 1
GA
7654


Name 1
GA
8888


Name 2
CA
9090


Name 2
CA
3456


Name 2
CA
7222



and I want it to look like this:



Entity Name
State
Count of stores




Name 2
CA
4



TX
1


Name 1
GA
2



AL
1


Name 3
TX
1



Essentially, I have been able to do this in a pivot table in Excel but I am unable to replicate this in Pandas for some reason and I really need help. I need the Entity Names sorted in descending order of Count of Stores (so in the above example, Name 2 will come up first because there are a total of 5 stores under Name 2, followed by Name 1 which has 3 stores total, and Name 3 which only has 1 store). Within the Entity Name grouping, I need the stores to be counted per state which is also in descending order as shown above. Ultimately, I want to put it in this format so I can graph this data as shown here
I am not sure why this is so difficult in Pandas but I am unable to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated! TIA!
I've tried many solutions posted in StackOverflow but I keep failing at the first level of sorting by the total count of stores by Entity.
The result I keep getting looks something like this:



Entity Name
State
count




Name 2
CA
4


Name 1
AL
1



GA
2


Name 3
TX
1


Name 2
TX
1




One option is to first sort the dataframe based on just Entity Name:
sort_indices = (df
                .groupby('Entity Name')
                .State
                .transform('size')
                # sort in descending order,
                # largest value comes first
                .argsort()[::-1])
sorted_df = df.iloc[sort_indices]
sorted_df
  Entity Name State  Store#
8     Name 2    CA     7222
7     Name 2    CA     3456
6     Name 2    CA     9090
3     Name 2    CA      123
1     Name 2    TX     4545
5     Name 1    GA     8888
4     Name 1    GA     7654
0     Name 1    AL     1234
2     Name 3    TX     6789

Next step is to group sorted_df based on a combination of Entity Name and State, and compute the size. Ensure the grouping is not sorted, so the original form is respected:
(sorted_df
.groupby(['Entity Name', 'State'],sort=False,as_index=False)
.agg(count_of_stores=('State','size'))
)
  Entity Name State  count_of_stores
0     Name 2    CA                 4
1     Name 2    TX                 1
2     Name 1    GA                 2
3     Name 1    AL                 1
4     Name 3    TX                 1

Another option, where you groupby only once:
out=(df
     .drop(columns='Store#')
     .groupby(['Entity Name', 'State'],sort=False)
     .value_counts()
     .rename('count_stores')
     )
out
Entity Name  State
Name 2       CA       4
Name 1       GA       2
             AL       1
Name 2       TX       1
Name 3       TX       1
Name: count_stores, dtype: int64

Next generate indices based on the current positions of Entity Name values:
indexer = out.index.get_level_values('Entity Name').factorize()[0].argsort()
(out
.iloc[indexer]
# reset only if you need to
#.reset_index()
)
Entity Name  State
Name 2       CA       4
             TX       1
Name 1       GA       2
             AL       1
Name 3       TX       1
Name: count_stores, dtype: int64

